# Configuring the connection in AWS with a Database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

recently I made an account in AWS, uploaded my project in github and installed it in EC2. When I run the link - http://ec2-54-213-242-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/BlueDrive/bluedrive/drive/public/ I get some errors. Well that's obvious because i haven't set a DB in AWS. Despite the fact that in `config/database.php` i editted some of the parameters such as host, in the error it still displays that the host is `localhost`. Why is that?! Also I would like to ask how to make a DB in AWS, create the tables and so on. Can I somehow import my `db.sql` with all the relations in the tables?

Comment: You can simply install Mysql and create your schema on AWS EC2 instance and then connect it with AWS EC2 application instance.

Comment: The problem could be specific to your application if the database hostname change is not reflected in the application.

Comment: @jbird What do you mean?